# Pause and resume circle progress bar in android

Tags: android

How can I pause and resume circle progress bar in android?

```
public void run(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (pStatus<100){
                pStatus += 1;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setProgress(pStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I need any examples of circle progress (can pause and resume).

Comment: Is it possible to make a boolean variable (for pause and resume) and also check that variable  inside the while statement with condition to increase the pstatus for example if paused then not to increase the pstatus variable and if resumed then increased that variable and this boolean variable set by the pause and resume button.

Comment: @ Rajan Bhavsar : may suggest me with your code, thanks

Comment: Ok let me try for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed the demo application the source code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private int pStatus = 0;
boolean resumed = true;
private TextView textView;
Button button1;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (resumed) {
                resumed = false;
            } else {
                resumed = true;
            }
        }
    });

    run();

}

public void run() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (pStatus < 100) {
                if (resumed) {
                    pStatus += 1;
                }
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setProgress(pStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

the actvity_main.xml file as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:progress="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="Paused" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

i am able to pause and resume the progress bar you can also please try this code.

Comment: Have you tested the code ? or done with this or getting any error in this code please suggest me if any changes or implementation needed

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, I appreciate it, I will soon feedback

Comment: Isn't this for a Horizontal Progress Bar? Will this work for Circular Progress bar?